# DB2 Trigger change in one step

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, db2-400

I need to update a lot DB2 triggers.

My way actually is to drop and create the trigger.
e.g.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ABC.DELETE_V68_BVVVSP2_V68JOURNAL ; 
CREATE TRIGGER ABC.DELETE_V68_BVVVSP2_V68JOURNAL [..]
```

but the risk is that the first command is processed and the second not - then I my trigger is off and it misses database actions.

Is there any way on DB2 to let this run in one step or any command like..

```
Update TRIGGER... 
RECREATE TRIGGER...
```

The OS is i5 Release 4.
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-trigger/db2-create-trigger/ you can use create or replace?

Comment: I don't have v5.4 doc at hand, but it should have [LOCK TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=statements-lock-table) statement. So use `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE; DROP ...; CREATE ...; COMMIT;` **in the same transaction**.

Comment: Thanks!! "create or replace" works! You have helped me at LOT.

Comment: Note that replacing a trigger will cause it to be executed as the last in order in case there are multiple trigger on a table, event (ins, upd, del) and activation time (before, after, instead of). See [order in which the triggers are activated](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=objects-triggers).

Comment: Thanks Peter, good to know. For the moment we have only one for esch table